# Posting codeable object

Tags: api, swift4

I have a codeable class:

```
struct Authentication : Codable
{
   let grant_type : String = "password"
   let client_id : String = "6_46db26s9zag4s4w80gc08cso804go4goccg88kcwoso0og5goo"
   let username : String
   let password : String
}
```

In which I need posting to a RESTful API so I call this function on button click:

```
let url = URL(string: ApiUrl().GetUri(uri: ApiUri().LoginURL))
    var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    let jsonData = try! encoder.encode(Authentication(username: txtUsername.text!, password: txtPassword.text!))

    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonData, options: [])

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data:Data?, response:URLResponse?, error:Error?) in
        if let safeData = data{
            print("response: \(String(data:safeData, encoding:.utf8))")
        }
    }
```

However for some reason as soon as it lands in this method I get this exception:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:options:error:]: Invalid top-level type in JSON write'
```

Am I doing the POST request wrong or something? I'm not entirely sure why I'm getting this error, does anyone else understand why?

Answer (score 0):

You are serializing the struct **twice** – the `JSONEncoder` does the job already –  which cannot work

Replace

```
request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonData, options: [])
```

with

```
request.httpBody = jsonData
```

And **do not** ignore errors. Handle them!